# Child Pull Request Automatically Merged to Master

Tags: git, github, git-merge, pull-request

I encountered an unexpected behavior with GitHub pull requests, and I need some clarification on the possible cause and how to avoid it in the future.

Here's what happened:

1. I had an initial pull request (PR1) in my GitHub repository with some changes.
2. I created a second pull request (PR2) using PR1 as a base and added a few additional changes on top of it.
3. I created third pull request (PR3) using PR2 as a base and added some more changes on top of it.
4. PR3 was reviewed and successfully merged into the "release" branch, which included all the commits/changes from PR1 and PR2 and the additional changes from PR3.
5. Later, the "release" branch was merged into the "master" branch, intending to release the changes in production.
6. Surprisingly, my older PR1 and PR2 was automatically merged into "master" alongside the changes from PR3 during the "release" to "master" merge.

I didn't expect PR1 and PR2 to be merged into "master" as it had already been superseded by PR3, which included all of PR1 and PR2 changes and some additional ones.

I would like to understand why this automatic merge of PR1 and PR2 into "master" occurred and how I can prevent it from happening in the future. Is there a way to maintain separate pull requests based on previous ones without causing unexpected merges during the "release" to "master" merge process?

Any insights, explanations, or best practices to handle such situations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Well.... I think step 4 tells the whole story.... Why do you think you would _not_ see PR1 and PR2's changes there?

Comment: If you wanted to only see `PR3` stuff being merged into another branch, you should have _cleaned up_ that branch by rebasing it... something like `git rebase --onto the-branch-I-want-to-merge-into PR2 PR3`.... it has been asked and answered maaaaany times over here in SO.

Comment: ... oh... and welcome to SO!

Comment: The changes themselves are correct; however, I did anticipate seeing the combined changes from both `PR1` and `PR2` in `PR3`, which was later merged into the `release` branch. However, what surprised me was that both `PR1` and `PR2`(raised against master) which were still in an open state till yesterday, were automatically merged into the `master` branch when merging `release` into `master` today.

Comment: That does not matter.... git does not know anything about PRs or them being open or anything else.... you ask to merge a branch, it includes all the history of both branches being merged, not just a little piece... and if just merging the `PR2..PR3` piece was your intent when merging, then you had to rebase the `PR3` branch to get rid of the changes introduced from `PR2` (which also contains changes from `PR1`).